# How to make a relationship beetween radiobuttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Please, help with this situation: how can I make relations (using jquery) between payment and delivery types? For example, if user choose "**Pre Order**" in payment - in delivery automatically checked "**Pre Order, delivery not available**". And if user choose "PayPal" he is given a choice between "**Mail Service**" and "**AIR MAIL**", but "*Pre Order, delivery not available*" is readonly. I appreciate your help.

```
<label>Payment type:</label>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="10" class="payment-item" id="pay-type-10" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"><label class="label" for="pay-type-10">Pre Order</label>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="11" class="payment-item" id="pay-type-11" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"><label class="label" for="pay-type-11">PayPal</label>
<br>
<label>Delivery type:</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="7" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-7" onclick="shEvOrd('delivery',this,1)"><label class="label" for="del-type-7">Pre Order, delivery not available</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="6" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-6" onclick="shEvOrd('delivery',this,1)"><label class="label" for="del-type-6">Mail Service</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="5" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-5" onclick="shEvOrd('delivery',this,1)"><label class="label" for="del-type-5">AIR MAIL</label>

<input type="button" value="Place order" id="order-button" onclick="shopCheckOut();this.order.reset">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
// attach a click event to the payment radio group
$(".payment-item").click(function(){

    var payment = $("input:radio[name='payment']:checked").val(), // check the current value
        isPaypal = payment !== "10", // a simple check to see what was selected
        delivery = $("#del-type-7"); // get the radio element with the pre-order option           


    return delivery.prop({
        // Disabled if `isPaypal` is true
        disabled: isPaypal,
        // Checked if `isPaypal` is true
        checked: !isPaypal
    });      
});
```

Have a look at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasonnathan/3s3Nn/2/

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wicun/1/edit)**

All you need:

```
var $delType7 = $("#del-type-7");       // Cache your elements
$("[name='payment']").click(function(){
    var PPal = $("[name='payment'][value='10']").is(':checked'); // Boolean
    $delType7.prop({checked:!PPal, disabled:PPal}); // boolean to toggle states
});
```

<sub>Remove `onclick` from HTML</sub>

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/prop/